# imap_open on gmail email goes in timeout when I try to read INBOX

Tags: php, gmail, imap, gmail-imap

the code used to work to read a gmail email right now does not work anymore.

This is the code:

```
imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX", "user", "password") or die ('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

I get this error:

> imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}INBOX

If I use this code (without INBOX) initially it worked (like twice) and right now does not work anymore:

```
imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl/novalidate-cert}", "user", "password") or die ('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());
```

I allowed third part applications to access the gmail account, but right now I do not know howto solve it.
Did google block reading gmail programmatically with imap?

Comment: *"Did google block reading gmail programmatically with imap"* .. No I don't think google did that, open your email from the web interface (and check for any security warnings, they usually warn you when new IMAP client connects to your email ). Also open from another client that uses IMAP like Thunderbird, If Thunderbird works, then the problem is not from google.

Comment: @Accountantم I do not know why the code previously worked like a charm right now does not work anymore